# how to find crlf line separators with git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

as I want to commit to git using intellij, I get a message

`You are about to commit CRLF line separators to the Git repository`

and I am given 2 options:

- fix and commit (runs `git config --global core.autocrlf`)
- commit as is

I would like to see where those line separators are before I do anything else.

How can I do that with git or intellij? (solutions using only git are preferred).

Comment: At the meantime I committed one file after another, until I found the culprit. This is obviously not a solution to the problem but a brute force workaround if someone is reading this and needs to move forward.. 
The file with the crlf was a file from a submodule I had so I decided to leave it as is - which shows how important finding the file first was.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use `git grep` via the command line to search for files containing the windows style newline characters.

Using the git bash you can find all files which contain a `\r` character via the following command (bash only!):

```
git grep -Il $'\r'
```

Or alternativly (which should work for all shell types - except windows ones):

```
git grep -Il '<CTRL + M>'
```

This will actually display as a newline in your shell, but as long as you wrap it into quotes it will work.

And finally for the windows CLI (tested with CMD and PowerShell):

```
git grep -Il "\r"
```

---

**Used options**

- `-I` excludes binary files from the match
- `-l` shows only the file names with matches, rather than all matches

Also, if you want to restrict your search on a number of files you can use the `--cached` option, which will only search in files you have on your index.

You can read the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) for more information.

Comment: can you update this answer for macOS sierra (10.12.6)?

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki The first version works just fine on a mac; it's a unix shell after all.

Comment: Based on the knowledge which files contain windows line separators I have been able to replace them with this command: `sed -i 's/\r//' file_with_CRLF` (on linux with bash).

Answer (score 2):

I just did it:

-fix and commit (runs git config --global core.autocrlf)

There are two ways to represent a line ending in a source code file.

- CRLF (carriage return + line feed);
- or just LF (line feed).

Git/Programming standards in general prefer LF.

Clicking Fix and Commit will configure Git to just always automatically convert line endings to LF before it commits.

However, I would suggest to use the @Sascha Wolf's answer and try to find out if your target file should be changed or kept as is.